# Can MCPCBs be used for audio frequency and/or MCU clock frequency applications?

Tags: pcb, frequency

For purely aesthetic reasons<sup>1</sup>, *not* for heat dissipation, I am contemplating using MCPCBs for these two applications:

- Audio frequency circuits, such as a Baby 8 sequencer, Atari Punk console,  synthesizer filters, audio effects, etc., and;
- MCU circuits, such as so called "barebones" Arduino projects, where an ATmega328P-PU is employed, and a clock frequency of 8-20 MHz is used.

Would I encounter any adverse effects (capacitive or otherwise) due to the higher frequency ranges used (when compared to DC, or 50 Hz AC, high power LED applications)? I initially assumed that the metal substrate would act as a PCB wide ground plane, and therefore not cause any problems. However, after thinking about it a bit, I am not so sure.

I have seen MCPCB applications for audio amplifiers, so I assume that, for the former, there aren't any issues. For the MCU applications, would the several orders of magnitude higher frequency of the crystal/clock be an issue?

FWIW, the metal substrate would be of the thicker variety, 3.2 mm or higher, ideally 5 - 10 mm. MCPCB dimensions would be limited to a maximum of 120 x 500 mm, but typically 100 x 200 (or less) mm.

Here is an example of an MCPCB used for an LED:

[image: LEDs on Metal-Core PCBs]

---

<sup>1</sup> For live performance of Chiptunes, ByteBeat, and the such like.

Comment: I'm confused: MCPCB: Metal **core** PCB. How does your audience even *see* the core? it's hidden below a thick layer of lacquer, typically.

Comment: Very small bars, clubs and gatherings, intimate and close environment... People can quite easily see the equipment and examine it and ask questions. It's not that confusing really, and besides the point which I am asking.

Comment: yeah, but I'd need a magnifying glass to tell a normal opaquely lacquered FR4 PCB from a metal core PCB, so what do you expect your audience to bring to your club? Can you point to a photo of what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe you are going to the wrong clubs? Along the lines of [this](http://gr33nonline.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/6071_highpowered_leds_7.jpg)

Comment: Might be the case! I've never seen anyone run around with a magnifying lens!

Comment: seriously, though, I'm intrigued in what look you're looking for. Happen to have a link to an example?

Comment: Because to me, a Metal Core PCB looks like [this](https://uk.beta-layout.com/images/aluplatte-ims-bestueckungsdruck-stopplack.jpg) and a "normal" FR4 PCB looks like [this](https://file.allpcb.com//web/16/09/29/203455218.jpg) and **I** couldn't tell them apart. Just boards with traces in some places and white, green, blue, black lacquer. But you're clearly thinking of something different! So, I wonder what you've got in mind!

Comment: ah, thanks for the picture, so you expect the people to look at the sides of the PCB?

Comment: It's not just the look. Maybe *aesthetic* was the wrong word... it would be a combination of the look and feel, as well as its *un-usualness* (or rather *uniqueness*) - A sort of USP (Unique Selling Point) if you will... These events are not for your typical run-of-the-mill audiences.

Comment: In addition, if a thicker substrate was to be used, then the weight would be of interest. Similar to a thick glass platter on a high end record deck - you don't *really* need it if you are only 50 ('cos you won't be able to hear the difference), but it gives a *feel good* factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you're right: That metal plane is typically nothing but a big ground plane.

There's one electrical difference: That thick ground plane is typically only the thickness of some isolating paint away from the trace, which is far less than the 0.8mm – 1.6 mm of the average fiberglass substrate thickness of two-layer PCBs.

That makes a difference for high-frequency circuitry, where the *wave impedance* of a trace matters, and the signal isn't actually carried by the conducting trace, but as wave in the isolator.

However, that's *RF*, not 20 MHz digital – you should be fine.

Note that MCPCBs are typically a pain to solder by hand (exactly the reason you use them – they carry heat away fast), and that you can't have vias through them – and that really limits their usefulness!

Comment: Note that if the track width to MCPCB dielectric thickness ratio were 10:1 the impedance is 15 Ohms and digital with 5ns risetime is 60MHz BW  This means you can use the smallest tracewidth that the Mfg can support to raise the impedance.  FR4 is the oppposite problem where you want thinner dielectric.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - thanks

Comment: Thanks Marcus, useful answer... :-)

Comment: higher W/h ratio is lower Zo and 0.1mm prepreg over MCPCB is 1/8th thick of a 32 mil FR4 so Zo reduces to 20% of FR4 Zo. Ask for 0.3mm prepreg or how to get 25 Ohm Zo for ATMega with trackwidth/thickness ratio ~5. I have never tried but Saturn PCB.exe tells you Zo on Conductor Impedance.  MCPCB thickness is not the issue. It is the extreme thin dielectric coating that gives very low Zo

Comment: then you can spray paint it Candy Apple Red. ☺☻♥­ after you raise the Zo

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they can. From [Metal Core PCB](http://www.agipcb.com/pcb-manufacturing/metal-core-pcb/) (emphasis is mine):

> Metal Core PCB applications:
>
> - Lighting : LED Light is the biggest user of Aluminum PCB
> - Power module: Power Converters ,Inverters, solid state relays, power rectifier bridges
> - Power supply: switching regulator, DC / AC converter, SW regulator
> - Communication electronic equipment: **high-frequency amplifier**, filter appliances, transmitter circuits
> - Audio equipment: input, output amplifiers, balanced amplifiers, audio amplifiers, preamplifiers, power amplifiers
> - Computer: **CPU boards**, floppy disk drives, power supply devices Office automation equipment: motor drives…
> - Power module: Inverters, solid state relays, power rectifier bridges
> - Car: Electronic regulator, ignition, power controllers…